# Boost MultiIndex - objects or pointers (and how to use them?)?

Tags: c++, boost, hash

I'm programming an agent-based simulation and have decided that Boost's MultiIndex is probably the most efficient container for my agents. I'm not a professional programmer, and my background is very spotty. I've two questions:

1. Is it better to have the container contain the agents (of class `Host`) themselves, or is it more efficient for the container to hold `Host *`? Hosts will sometimes be deleted from memory (that's my plan, anyway... need to read up on `new` and `delete`). Hosts' private variables will get updated occasionally, which I hope to do through the `modify` function in MultiIndex. There will be no other copies of Hosts in the simulation, i.e., they will not be used in any other containers.
2. If I use pointers to Hosts, how do I set up the key extraction properly? My code below doesn't compile.

```
// main.cpp - ATTEMPTED POINTER VERSION
...
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

typedef multi_index_container<
  Host *,
  indexed_by< 
    // hash by Host::id
    hashed_unique< BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEM_FUN(Host,int,Host::getID) > // arg errors here
    > // end indexed_by
  > HostContainer;

...
int main() {

   ...
   HostContainer testHosts;
   Host * newHostPtr;
   newHostPtr = new Host( t, DOB, idCtr, 0, currentEvents );
   testHosts.insert( newHostPtr );
   ... 
}
```

I can't find a precisely analogous example in the Boost documentation, and my knowledge of C++ syntax is still very weak. The code does appear to work when I replace all the pointer references with the class objects themselves.

---

As best I can read it, the Boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html) (see summary table at bottom) implies I should be able to use member functions with pointer elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `Host` contains lot of data you could use `shared_ptr` to avoid copying. You could use MultiIndex with `shared_ptr` in it:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct Host
{
   int get_id() const { return id; }
 private:
   int id;
   // more members here
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  boost::shared_ptr<Host>,    // use pointer instead of real Host
  indexed_by< 
    // hash using function Host::get_id
    hashed_unique< const_mem_fun<Host, int, &Host::get_id> >
    > // end indexed_by
  > HostContainer;
```

Then you could use it as follows:

```
int main()
{
   HostContainer testHosts;
   Host * newHostPtr;
   newHostPtr = new Host;
   testHosts.insert( boost::shared_ptr<Host>(newHostPtr) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll look into shared pointers--if I don't use a ptr, does that mean that each object is stored in two places in memory (once upon creation and then again in the container)? Also, Host is a class, and Host::id is a private member variable. I'm trying to figure out how to use the member function Host::getID() as my key extractor if HostContainer is full of Host * or shared_ptr<Host>...

Comment: Added member function `get_id` to my answer. If you do not use `shared_ptr` it means that every `Host` will be copied into MultiIndex container and copy will be there until you remove it from there.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error at the same line as before: "main.cpp:57: error: could not convert template argument ‘&Host::getID’ to ‘int (Host::*)()const’".

Comment: How your `getID` was defined? My sample compiles without errors.

Comment: In 'Host.cpp,' it's const int Host::getID( void ) {
  return id;
}

Comment: Your function is not `const`. You should define it as `int Host::getID( void ) const { return id; }` since elements in a multi_index_container are treated as constant.

Comment: Now it compiles! Thank you! I tried to read off the ids with an iterator, starting at HostContainer::iterator it = testHosts.begin() and asking for it->getID(), and I'm getting ‘const class boost::shared_ptr<Host>’ has no member named ‘getID’. My syntax seems to agree with the examples I can find... many thanks again.

Comment: To get id from iterator you could write `(*it)->getID()` or `it->get()->getID()`.

Comment: Woooooo! Thank you! I had been thinking get() was extraneous. Will study Boost ptrs in more detail.